# Selenium test Automation : jquery select and verify whether text present ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing test automation using selenium, how to use jquery to select   9.0 GB from one of the table  and verify text (9.0 GB) present in the table?

All I need to do is for jquery to look into the table and look for particular text and verify that text is present. Below is the DOM :

```
<table id="usage-detail-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover footable tablefiltering footable-loaded dataTable no-footer default" role="grid">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
    <tr class="even" role="row">
    <td class="nowrap sorting_1 expand">
    <td class=" nowrap">Primary</td>
    <td class=" nowrap">
    <input type="hidden" value="9000010800">
    9.0 GB
    </td>
    <td class=" nowrap">
    <input type="hidden" value="8000000000">
    8.0 GB
    </td>
    <td class=" nowrap">
    <td class=" nowrap">
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
    <tr class="even" role="row">
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `filter()`. Example:

```
var result = '';
$('td').filter(function() {
    if($(this).html().indexOf('9.0 GB') >= 0){
        result = "Got";
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

More about jQuery [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am actually a newbie. Would you know a bit about Selenium Automation testing. Usually we write the code in this format :

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("jQuery('#dhcp-lease-xlan').trigger('change')");

How would I implement your code using the above format? Thank you in advance.